# Special Attacks?

Tags: rune-factory-tod

It's been awhile since I've played Tides of Destiny. I just got back on and managed to level my Katana skill to 13, and I got a prompt that said I "unlocked the Katana's special attack". I know that each weapon has several different unique attacks (that are not Rune Abilities), but I forgot how to use each one. How do I perform these attacks and is there anywhere in-game where I can look them up?

Answer (score 2):

There are four types of unlockable attacks for all the weapons: charge, dash, aerial special, and ultimate.

*Charge Attack* - Pressing and holding the attack button starts the charge attack. Once charged, your character will attack, launch the target into the air, and jump to follow. You can then proceed to air combo while the target monster is vulnerable.

*Dash Attack* - Dash attacks are activated by running a short distance and pressing the attack button. Dash attacks are quick strikes, often suited for hit-and-run tactics when you're fighting a large mob of monsters.

*Aerial Special* - Aerial Special differ between weapons, although activating an aerial special is straightforward. Once in the air, press either Triangle + X (PS3) or A + B (Wii) to use the aerial special.

*Ultimate Attack* - The last unlockable skill, the ultimate attack is a continuation of your ground combo. True to its name, the ultimate attack is pretty ultimate. You deal greater damage as you continue your combo and you are invincible for the entirety of the ultimate attack portion of your ground combo.